# Why can't I use coordinate in coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

In

```tex
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.17, % Specify the compatibility version
    nice_axis/.style={
        samples=101,
        domain=-2:2,
        % title={Triangle Function},
        xmax=1.2,
        xmin=-1.2,
        ymax=1.2,
        ymin=-1.2,
        ytick={0},
        xtick={0},
        % grid=both,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={->},
        xlabel={$\Im{s\left( t \right)}$},
        ylabel={$\Re{s\left( t \right)}$},
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.5)},anchor=west},
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,1)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
        legend pos=outer north east
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    nice_axis,
  ]

    \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:360, samples=100, smooth] ({cos(x)}, {sin(x)});
    
    \addplot[red, thick, mark=*, data cs=polar] coordinates {
        (30,1)
    } coordinate (angle30);
    \addplot[blue, thick, mark=*, yshift=10pt] coordinates{
        (angle30)
    };

  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I was expecting `angle30` as I usually do in `\draw` command, but I am getting

```
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine
 of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `-120.0'
. The unreadable part was near '-120.0'..
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, because you're puzzling a point on a canvas `(angle30)` with a data format `(x,y)`, which happen to have a similar name and just by chance looks similar on code-level. But these are different representations, with different meanings, in different scopes and contexts. See the orange line below.

---

Let's disassemble your command, which may be oversimplified, but should show you the idea.

```
\addplot[red, thick, mark=*, data cs=polar] coordinates {
        (30,1)
    } coordinate (angle30);
```

So this command says:

- start a path (`\`) and end it later (`;`)
- do some `action` in between (like in a movie)
- the first action shall be whatever is hidden in `addplot`
- once you're done remember to last position: `coordinate`
- and call it `angle30`
- NOW finish the path `;`

While `\draw[orange] (angle30) -- +(1,1);` would state:

- start a path `\`
- do some action hidden in `draw`
- start at position on canvas which you stored in `angle30` earlier
- draw a line, in relative coordinates
- finish this path `;`

---

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.17, % Specify the compatibility version
    nice_axis/.style={
        samples=101,
        domain=-2:2,
        % title={Triangle Function},
        xmax=1.2,
        xmin=-1.2,
        ymax=1.2,
        ymin=-1.2,
        ytick={0},
        xtick={0},
        % grid=both,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={->},
        xlabel={$\Im{s\left( t \right)}$},
        ylabel={$\Re{s\left( t \right)}$},
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.5)},anchor=west},
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,1)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
        legend pos=outer north east
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    nice_axis,
  ]

    \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:360, samples=100, smooth] ({cos(x)}, {sin(x)});
    
    \addplot[red, thick, mark=*, data cs=polar] coordinates {
        (30,1)
    } coordinate (angle30);
%    \addplot[blue, thick, mark=*, yshift=10pt] coordinates{
%        (angle30)
%    };

    \draw[orange] (angle30) -- +(1,1);

  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know I am wrong, but I still see `(30,1)` (which is labeled to `(angle30)`) as `(x,y)`: both seem to be a point in canvas, one in Cartesian and the other in polar coordinates. Interestingly, however, is that `(30,1)` didn't print a dot, as I was expecting to, but a dot and a line. I have no idea how this line came about. The initial position is clearly `(30,1)`, but the final position and the shape (a line, a curve...) is unclear to me.

Comment: If you mean the orange line: I put it there. Its length is sqrt(2) cm = 1.414cm, BTW, which is not the same length as 1 at 30 deg …

Comment: My bad, I just overlooked `\draw[orange] (angle30) -- +(1,1);`. Anyway, I still see `(30,1)` (which is labeled to (`angle30`)) as `(x,y)`: both seem to be a point in canvas, one in Cartesian and the other in polar coordinates.

Comment: Final remark: one is **output** (of some canvas transformations), the other one is **input** (of data), hence incompatible. To see this more easily, add more coordinates. // You may also want to have a look into the source codes of tikz and pgfplots for further insight.